# non consumable in-app purchase :: parse.com :: close but no cigar

Tags: parse-platform, in-app-purchase

I've got a menu option that I want to protect with a $.99c in-App purchase.  If the user has paid then the menu item is enabled, else, tapping on that menu item prompts them to buy.

Here is what I have so far.  When I tap on the menu item it rightly invokes the apple IAP confirmation screen. Everything looks great so far, but, as soon as I click on "Buy", it errors out but am not sure how to trap on the error.  The IAP is not performed.

Take a look.
Why would my PFPurchase method be failing?
How do I capture the error number coming back?  (I am seeing "Error: (null)")

[image]

In my app delegate I have the following:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////                      in-App Purchase                    //////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
hiLobetPURCHASED = NO;
// Use the product identifier from iTunes to register a handler.
[PFPurchase addObserverForProduct:@"hilobet100" block:^(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction) {
    // Write business logic that should run once this product is purchased.
        hiLobetPURCHASED = YES;
    NSLog(@"observing purchases for hilobet100");
}];
```

and at the point of sale I have:

```
[PFPurchase buyProduct:@"hilobet100" block:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"hang on trying to get it for you");

    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"congrats, you are the proud owner of the hilo bet");
        if ([switchHiLow isOn]) {
            [btnSettingsHiLo  setEnabled:YES];
            [btnSettingsHiLo  setHidden:NO];
        } else {
            [btnSettingsHiLo  setEnabled:NO];
            [btnSettingsHiLo  setHidden:YES];
        }
    } else NSLog(@"there was an error in the purchase");

}];
```

All i get is the error message.  See anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the specific error failing in the *buyProduct* call, change

`NSLog(@"there was an error in the purchase");`

to

`NSLog(@"there was an error (error: %@) in the purchase", error);`

Comment: Thanks, John.  That did the trick on getting error message spit out.  I then was able to look up the error message to see that there is a lot of chatter out there saying that the IAP testing works fine with real phone but not as fine with simulators...  I tried on my phone and the above code works.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Once I got the error message to spit out properly (see answer candidate #1) I then was able to look up the error message to see that there is a lot of chatter out there saying that the IAP testing works fine with real phone but not as fine with simulators... I tried on my phone and the above code works.